# How to open LogCat in Eclipse (for Android Debug)

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, logcat

I'm debugging my Android App from book I bought. In book says (and shows on PrintScreen in book), that I need to look at LogCat Console. But I don't have it opened in my Eclipse. I searched in options, but I couldn't find how to open it.

How open LogCat console?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LogCat is located here:

Window > Show View > Other > Android > LogCat

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's available here:

In Eclipse, Goto Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat.

You can find commands and stuff you can do with logcat over here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html