# ERROR RuntimeException when debug java file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to debug this. I parse some nodes via json and i try to find the shortest path running Dijkstra algorithm:

```
class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
{
public final String name;
public Edge[] adjacencies;

public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
public Vertex previous;
public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
public String toString() { return name; }
public int compareTo(Vertex other)
{
    return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
}

}


class Edge
{
public final Vertex target;
public final double weight;
public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight)
{ target = argTarget; weight = argWeight; }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Dijkstra
{
public static void computePaths(Vertex source)
{
    source.minDistance = 0.;
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    vertexQueue.add(source);

    while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
    Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

        // Visit each edge exiting u
        for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
        {
            Vertex v = e.target;
            double weight = e.weight;
            double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
    if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
        vertexQueue.remove(v);
        v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
        v.previous = u;
        vertexQueue.add(v);
    }
        }
    }
}

public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target)
{
    List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
        path.add(vertex);

    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void mainb()
{
     final  String url = "http://dynamicsoftworks.gr/pacman-srv/admin/json.php";

        // JSON Node names
     ArrayList<Vertex> ar2vertex = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
          final String TAG_LEVEL = "Level";
          final String TAG_MAIN = "main";
          final String TAG_CONN = "conn";
          final String TAG_ID = "id";
          final String TAG_DISTANCE = "distance";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray contacts = null;
        JSONArray conn = null;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        // Hashmap for ListView
        //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_LEVEL);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable

                String main = c.getString(TAG_MAIN);

                conn = c.getJSONArray(TAG_CONN);
                ArrayList<Edge> ar2edge = new ArrayList<Edge>();
                ArrayList<Edge> armainedge = new ArrayList<Edge>();
                ArrayList<Vertex> armainedge2 = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
                ArrayList<Vertex> allvertexes = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
                ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<Double> ar2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
                for(int is = 0; is < conn.length(); is++){
                    JSONObject d = conn.getJSONObject(is);
                    String ida = d.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String dinstance = d.getString(TAG_DISTANCE);
                    ar.add(ida);
                    ar2.add(Double.parseDouble(dinstance));                    
                }

                ArrayList<Vertex> arvertex = new ArrayList<Vertex>();

                // creating new HashMap
                ar2vertex.add(new Vertex(main.toString()));
                allvertexes.add(new Vertex(main.toString()));
                for (int kk=0;kk<ar.size();kk++){
                    //Vertex  nodes[];
                    arvertex.add(new Vertex(ar.get(kk)));
                }

             //   Edge[] aListOfEdges = null;

            //EDWWWWW PROBL!!!    
                for (int kk=0;kk<arvertex.size();kk++){
               // v0.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge[]{(nodes[kk],  distanses[kk])}};
                    Edge edges = new Edge(arvertex.get(kk),ar2.get(kk));
                    ar2edge.add(edges);
                }



                Edge[] edges3 = ar2edge.toArray(new Edge[ar2edge.size()]);




                for (int kp=0;kp<arvertex.size();kp++){
                    ar2vertex.get(i).adjacencies = edges3 ;
               // System.out.println("nodes: " + ar2vertex.get(i).adjacencies);
                }

                computePaths(ar2vertex.get(0));
               for(int mm=0;mm<ar2vertex.size();mm++){

                List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(ar2vertex.get(mm));
                //Log.d("Test", "TAB: " + "\t" + "AAAAAAAA" + "\t" + "AAAAAAAAA"); 
               System.out.println("Path: " + path);
               }
                //Arrays.fill(ids, null);
                //Arrays.fill(distanses, 0);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





/*  Vertex v0 = new Vertex("par1");
Vertex v1 = new Vertex("par2");
Vertex v2 = new Vertex("par3");
Vertex v3 = new Vertex("par4");
Vertex v4 = new Vertex("par5");
Vertex v5 = new Vertex("par6");
Vertex v6 = new Vertex("par7");

v0.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1,  79.83),
                             new Edge(v5,  81.15) };
v1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0,  79.75),
                             new Edge(v2,  39.42),
                             new Edge(v3, 103.00) };
v2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1,  38.65) };
v3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1, 102.53),
                             new Edge(v5,  61.44),
                             new Edge(v6,  96.79) };
v4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v5, 133.04) };
v5.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0,  81.77),
                             new Edge(v3,  62.05),
                             new Edge(v4, 134.47),
                             new Edge(v6,  91.63) };
v6.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v3,  97.24),
                             new Edge(v5,  87.94) };*/


}

public static String  fff(){
     return "hi";
}
}
```

but i get this error: 10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pvsgames.pacman/com.pvsgames.pacman.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at com.pvsgames.pacman.Dijkstra.computePaths(Dijkstra.java:53)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at com.pvsgames.pacman.Dijkstra.mainb(Dijkstra.java:169)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at com.pvsgames.pacman.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
10-12 00:33:22.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)

Comment: The full stack trace should tell you the exact place in the code where the NPE is thrown.

Comment: and how i get full stack trace ?

Comment: [How to open LogCat in Eclipse (for Android Debug)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769798/how-to-open-logcat-in-eclipse-for-android-debug)

Comment: i just edit my post but i cannot find the error