# android stock inventory program crashes

Tags: android, constructor

I am designing a stock inventory program which logs items with various attributes. I had it working and then went on to it reading from a text file on a sever and now whenever i try and edit the attributes and/or want to add a new item it crashes and I have no idea why. I believe its to do with the constructors but every thing I've tried hasn't worked.

below is the list element where the items are stored:

```
   public class ItemListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
    {
private ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter;
private ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    //retrieve list of students and set them in the adaptor
    ArrayList<Item> itemList = ((ItemApplication)getApplication()).getItemList();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);

    //assign adaptor to ListView
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.item_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.itemmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case R.id.enter_item_data:  
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EnterItemActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.get_network:
        System.err.println("Read started");
        GetDataFromServerTask  t = new GetDataFromServerTask();
        t.execute();
        return true;
    case R.id.send_network:
        System.err.println("Send to network");
    // comment out send code for now so we can test get- in isolation
        //SendDataToServerTask  st = new SendDataToServerTask();
        //st.execute();
        return true;
    case R.id.save:
        saveData();
        return true;
    case R.id.exit:
        saveData();
        finish();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    //start EnterStudentActivity with reference to list position
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, EnterItemActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void saveData() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void showItemList() 
{
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private class GetDataFromServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 

{
    private Socket socket = null;
    private PrintWriter out = null;
    private Scanner in = null;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void ... params) 
    {
        ArrayList<Item> ItemList = ((ItemApplication)getApplication()).getItemList();

        try 
        { 
            if (socket == null) 
            {
                InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
                socket = new Socket(ia, 4444);
                System.err.println("Created Socket");
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                System.err.println("Output stream created");
                in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }

            out.println("GET_LIST");;
            in.useDelimiter(",");

            while (in.hasNext()) 
            {
                String plant = in.next().trim();
                int day = Integer.parseInt(in.next().trim());
                int month = Integer.parseInt(in.next().trim());
                int year = Integer.parseInt(in.next().trim());
                int stockId = Integer.parseInt(in.next().trim());
                String nameOfItem = in.next().trim();
                int hour = 0;
                int minute = 0;
                String inspectorId = "";
                String stockUnits = "";
                String condition = "";
                String additional = "";     

                Item i = new Item(plant, day, month, year, stockId, nameOfItem, hour, minute, inspectorId, stockUnits, condition, additional, true);
                ItemList.add(i);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
            } 
                catch (UnknownHostException e) 
                {
                    System.err.println("Don't know about host: ");
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for " + "the connection to: ");
                } 
                catch (NullPointerException e) 
                {
                    System.err.println("Null pointer caught");
                    System.err.println(e.toString());
                }
            return null;    
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) 
        {
            ItemListActivity.this.showItemList();
        }
    }

  }
```

the next lot of code is the item's class:

```
 public class Item  
 {
private String plant;
private int day, month, year;
private int hour, minute;
private int stockId;
private String nameOfItem;
private String inspectorId;
private String stockUnits;
private String condition;
private String additional;
private boolean isFollowUp;

public Item(String plant, int day, int month, int year,  int stockId, String nameOfItem, int hour, int minute, String inspectorId, String stockUnits, String condition, String additional, boolean isFollowUp)
{
    this.plant = plant;
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
    this.stockId = stockId;
    this.nameOfItem = nameOfItem;
    this.inspectorId = getInspectorId();
    this.stockUnits = getStockUnits();
    this.condition = getCondition();
    this.additional = getAdditional();
    this.isFollowUp = isFollowUp();
}

public String getPlant() 
{
    return plant;
}

public boolean isFollowUp() 
{
    return isFollowUp;
}

@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return "Plant: " + plant + "\n" + "Inspection Date: " + day + ", " + (month +1) + ", " + year + 
            "\n" + "Inspection Time: " + hour + ":" + minute + "\n" + "Stock ID: " + stockId + "\n" + "Name of Item: " + nameOfItem + "\n" + "Inspector ID: "
            + inspectorId + "\n" + "Stock Units: " + stockUnits + "\n" + "Condition: " + condition + "\n" 
            + "Additional Info: " + additional +"\n" + "Follow-up? " + isFollowUp;
}

public Item(String plant, int day, int month, int year,  int stockId, String nameOfItem, int hour, int minute, String inspectorId, String stockUnits, String condition, String additional)
{
    this(plant, day, month, year, stockId, nameOfItem, hour, minute, inspectorId, stockUnits, condition, additional, true);
}

public int getDay() 
{
    return day;
}

public int getMonth() 
{
    return month;
}

public int getYear() 
{
    return year;
}

public void setPlant(String plant)
{
    this.plant = plant;
}

public void setDay(int day)
{
    this.day = day;
}

public void setMonth(int month)
{
    this.month = month;
}

public void setYear(int year)
{
    this.year = year;
}

public void setFollowUp(boolean isFollowUp)
{
    this.isFollowUp = isFollowUp;
}

public int getStockId() 
{
    return stockId;
}

public void setStockId(int stockId) 
{
    this.stockId = stockId;
}

public String getNameOfItem() 

{
    return nameOfItem;
}

public void setNameOfItem(String nameOfItem) 
{
    this.nameOfItem = nameOfItem;
}

public String getInspectorId() 
{
    return inspectorId;
}

public void setInspectorId(String inspectorId) 
{
    this.inspectorId = inspectorId;
}

public String getStockUnits()
{
    return stockUnits;
}

public void setStockUnits(String stockUnits) 
{
    this.stockUnits = stockUnits;
}

public String getCondition()
{
    return condition;
}

public void setCondition(String condition) 
{
    this.condition = condition;
}

public String getAdditional()
{
    return additional;
}

public void setAdditional(String additional)
{
    this.additional = additional;
}

public int getHour()
{
    return hour;
}

public void setHour(int hour)
{
    this.hour = hour;
}

public int getMinute()
{
    return minute;
}

public void setMinute(int minute)
{
    this.minute = minute;
}
  }
```

this last bit of code is the entering of the items attributes when entering a new item

```
    public class EnterItemActivity extends Activity implements OnEditorActionListener, OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener
    {
private EditText et;
private EditText etP;
private EditText etS;
private EditText etN;
private EditText etSU;
private EditText etA;
private DatePicker dp;
private CheckBox cb;
private TextView tvSC;
private RadioButton rbE;
private RadioButton rbS;
private RadioButton rbU;
private Item item;
private TextView tv;
private TimePicker tp;
private Spinner spin;
String[] idItems = {"1253", "3965" , "3234", "9912", "3423"};
private boolean isNew = true;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_item);

    etP = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_plant);
    etP.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    dp = (DatePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.dp_inspection_date);

    etS= (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_stock_id);
    etS.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    etN = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_name_of_item);
    etN.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    tp = (TimePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.tp_time_inspection);

    tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tv_inspector_id);
    tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tv_inspector_id_value);

    spin = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.sp_spinner_in_id);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter inspectorSpinner = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, idItems);
    inspectorSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(inspectorSpinner);

    etSU = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_stock_units);
    etSU.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    rbE = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rb_condition_excellent);
    rbS = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rb_condition_statisfactory);
    rbU = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rb_condition_unacceptable);
    tvSC = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tv_conditon_selected);

    etA = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_additional);
    etA.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    cb = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.cb_follow_up);

    //initialise the data if this is not a new student
    //get the student object to be updated
    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        isNew = false;
        int position = extras.getInt("position");
        item = ((ItemApplication)getApplication()).getItem(position);

        etP.setText(item.getPlant());
        etP.setFocusable(false); //can't update the name        
        dp.updateDate(item.getYear(), item.getMonth(), item.getDay());
        tp.setCurrentHour(item.getHour());
        tp.setCurrentMinute(item.getMinute());
        etS.setText(item.getStockId());
        etS.setFocusable(false);
        etN.setText(item.getNameOfItem());
        tv.setText(item.getInspectorId());
        etSU.setText(item.getStockUnits());
        tvSC.setText(item.getCondition());
        etA.setText(item.getAdditional());
        cb.setChecked(item.isFollowUp());

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.itemmenu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) 
{
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);

    return true;
}


public void onClick(View v) 
{
    //get the values for displaying in the list
    String plant = etP.getText().toString();
    int day = dp.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = dp.getMonth();
    int year = dp.getYear();
    int stockId = item.getStockId();
    String nameOfItem = etN.getText().toString();
    int hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
    int minute = tp.getCurrentMinute();
    String inspectorId = tv.getText().toString();
    String stockUnits = etSU.getText().toString();
    String condition = tvSC.getText().toString();
    String additional = etA.getText().toString();
    boolean isFollowUp= cb.isChecked();

        if (isNew)
        {
            item = new Item(plant, day, month, year, stockId, nameOfItem,  hour, minute, inspectorId, stockUnits, condition, additional, false);
            ((ItemApplication)getApplication()).addItem(item);
        }
        else
        {
            //update the student already in the list
            item.setPlant(plant);
            item.setDay(day);
            item.setMonth(month);
            item.setStockId(stockId);
            item.setNameOfItem(nameOfItem);
            item.setYear(year);
            item.setHour(hour);
            item.setMinute(minute);
            item.setInspectorId(inspectorId);
            item.setStockUnits(stockUnits);
            item.setCondition(condition);
            item.setAdditional(additional);
            item.setFollowUp(isFollowUp);
        }

        showItem(item);
    }

    public void showItem(Item i) 
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Item Details").setMessage(i.toString()).setNeutralButton("OK", this).show();         
    } 

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        tv.setText(idItems [position]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
    {
        tv.setText("");
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClickCondition(View view)
    {   
        if(rbE.isChecked())
        {
            tvSC.setText("Excellent");
        }
        else if(rbS.isChecked())
        {
            tvSC.setText("Satisfactory");
        }
        else if(rbU.isChecked())
        {
            tvSC.setText("Unacceptable");
        }
    }


     }
```

the log cat for the server crash:

```
 12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.assignmentfinal/com.example.assignmentfinal.EnterItemActivity}:            android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x100
 12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x100
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3640)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at com.example.assignmentfinal.EnterItemActivity.onCreate(EnterItemActivity.java:103)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
```

12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    12-02 14:56:07.903: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     ... 11 more

below is the logcat for the application crashing when a brand new item is added:

```
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     ... 11 more
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at com.example.assignmentfinal.EnterItemActivity.onClick(EnterItemActivity.java:141)
12-02 15:07:03.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: A logcat would be very appreciated --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769798/how-to-open-logcat-in-eclipse-for-android-debug

Comment: Without your logcat, we've no idea why either. When it crashes, you'll see messages in red. Please post them as part of your question.

Comment: in which class are you talking bout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in onCreate within EnterItemActivity and is a Resources$NotFoundException.
In the logcat, you can see that this results from a call to:

```
android.widget.TextView.setText
```

In onCreate, you call setText in several places. It is this one that is the problem:

```
etS.setText(item.getStockId());
```

Your method returns an int, not a String:

```
public int getStockId() 
{
    return stockId;
}
```

The setText method has two overloads. When called with a string value, that is the text to be used. When called with an int, that integer number refers to a resource id and Android cannot find a resource for the id value provided. I suspect you want to just show the value of stockId as a string. So you can change your method to instead be:

```
public String getStockId() 
{
    return String.valueOf(stockId);
}
```

...or leave the method as it is and use:

```
etS.setText(String.valueOf(item.getStockId()));
```

Comment: it still crashes when a new item is added to the list

Comment: There aren't enough clues in the LogCat for me to spot the problem this time (other than it's a null pointer exception somewhere in the onClick method). I think it's time to use the debugger if you've already done so to step through line by line. Just set a breakpoint at the start of the onClick and start under debug. You may want to consider a new question if this bug is not related to the first.

Comment: i think it is the same problem as the previous with this line **int stockId = item.getStockId();** becuase the value i need is in aa text field called etS but im not calling that because you cant with an int

Comment: You can always convert an int to a String with String.valueOf? Or a String to an int with Integer.parseInt? So you could actually take it from etS?