# Android Cursor, moveToNext() error

Tags: android, cursor

Why moveToNext() should be given after getString()? If it wasn't, app crashes!

```
for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
{
    result+= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));                 
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: you have to `c.moveToNext();` before calling `c.getString`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (c.moveToFirst()){
   while(!c.isAfterLast()){
      String productNames[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
//Maybe a string array is better than one long string?
      i++
      c.moveToNext();
   }
}
c.close();
```

[How to retrieve data from cursor class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810615/how-to-retrieve-data-from-cursor-class/13106289#13106289)

See Some Noob Student 's answer about syntax. You're not using the 'i' index in your code above to specify what row you are reading from - only the number of times you concatenate the product names string. It reads the same row n count times!

[use of cursor in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938471/use-of-cursor-in-android)

This question has a good answer explaining what a cursor is. I think of it as a temporary table (Spreadsheet).

movetoNext() moves the 'cursor' (think highlighted spreadsheet rectangle) to the next row of "productname" column (the next product's name).

It could be crashing for a lot of reasons, maybe productname is not a column in cursor 'c'. Here is a question about debugging that may be useful [How to debug android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513296/how-to-debug-android-project)
The old step through then examine the last exception/error method should do the trick.